# Show content on scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my post content to stay hidden until the user scrolls ([example](http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/TRAnfaf5y/screen_shot_2014-11-19_at_13.05.50.png)). So far I haven't been successful.

So far I have this code -

jQuery -

```
$('.content-post').hide();
$('div').on('scroll', function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 25)$('.content-post').show();
else $('.content-post').hide();
});
```

CSS -

```
.content-post { 
background-color: #EDE3DE;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="content-post">  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx091t2w/7/) and my [website](http://katiedev.com/hu2/uncategorized/fghsrgdfc/)

I am currently studying jQuery so please go easy :)

Comment: What has your example to do with your question? I can only see a picture of a woman and some words... Also: Why are you applying the scroll event on a div? Most likely your window object (window.scrollY) will scroll. Check what it is that scrolls and adjust the code.

Comment: The example is what I'm trying to achieve. And I'm using the jQuery on my website - http://tinyurl.com/k4rzfy5

Answer (score 0):

css

```
body{
    height:2000px;
}
```

if the box parent is more big it the child, now works the on-scroll!

[image: image scroll]

```
$('.content-post').hide();

//$(document).scroll(function(){
//$(document).on('scroll', function(){
$(document).bind('scroll', function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 25) {
     console.log($(this).scrollTop());
     $('.content-post').show();
  } else {
     $('.content-post').hide();
  }
});
```